# Method executed before 'await' method complete

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, async-await, react-native-push-notification

Trying to perform setState after the value return from `checkPermissions()`, however **async-await** didn't do the job.

I can't spot anything incorrect here, can you point out my mistake?
FYI `checkPermissions()` accept a callback function as parameter.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let authorizationStatus = false;
    await PushNotification.checkPermissions(function(permissions) { 
      console.log(permissions); 
      authorizationStatus = permissions.alert
      console.log('Run first')
    });

    console.log('Run after')
    this.setState({
     authorizationStatus,
    });
  }
```

Check Permissions Code (Android)

```
@ReactMethod
    public void checkPermissions(Promise promise) {
      ReactContext reactContext = getReactApplicationContext();
      NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(reactContext);
      promise.resolve(managerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled());
    }
```

Solution tried but failed:
Only `Run first` is printed out, `Run after` does not.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let authorizationStatus = false;
    PushNotification.checkPermissions(function(permissions) { 
      console.log(permissions); 
      authorizationStatus = permissions.alert
      console.log('Run first')
      this.setState({
       authorizationStatus,
      },()=>{console.log('Run after')});

    });
  }
```

Comment: If it accepts a callback function, it isn't promisified yet. Which means it doesn't return a Promise, and putting `await` in front has no effect. The fix here is simple: just move the `setState` part into the callback.

Comment: Does `PushNotification.checkPermissions` actually return a `Promise` to be `await`ed?

Comment: @ChrisG Updated question. I actually tried this before, however setState does not get performed.

Comment: There's a trailing comma after `authorizationStatus` but I don't see any way that it would print `Run first` but not `Run after`. Are you showing us actual code? Or did you edit it for the question here?

Comment: @ChrisG I only did masking to the code, otherwise these are the code I have in my project. I tried removing comma after `authorizationStatus`, it didn't work either.

Comment: I assume you're getting `this.setState is not a function`? That's because you need to use an arrow function instead, otherwise `this` no longer points to your Component instance. If you do that, it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-cdn-tw8dd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh. I'm not getting `this.setState is not a function`, weirdly it went through..BUT You are right about this, I forgotten about `this` keyword scope in `function` and `arrow function`. You're the man @ChrisG. Would you post your answer? I'm accepting your solution (:

Answer (score 0):

You are presumably looking for

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const permissions = await PushNotification.checkPermissions();
  console.log(permissions); 
  const authorizationStatus = permissions.alert
  console.log('Run first');

  console.log('Run after')
  this.setState({authorizationStatus});
}
```

You can only `await` a promise, you don't want to pass a callback.

Comment: it's not my option to pass callback instead of getting a promise. That's what the library decided.

Comment: @TommyLeong OK, then you need to [promisify it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) yourself. But from the android declaration you posted it looked as if the method would already support promises natively.